# Custom Implicit Casting vs. Public Property

Tags: c#, properties, casting

Ok so I have a Top-level class that is used to monitor a bunch of different values, which range from value types to reference types. Now my question is what is the difference between setting up implicit casting for the top level class instead of setting up public properties.

Some code to illustrate.

This:

```
 public static implicit operator int(TopLevel TP)
 {
       return TP.DataLevel1.DataLevel2.DataLeverl3.Data;
 }
```

Compared to:

```
 public int DataLevel3Value
 {
      get
      {
          return this.DataLevel1.DataLevel2.DataLeverl3.Data;
      }
 }
```

Is there a reason I would not want to do the Implicit version compared to the Property version? Also is the code bellow valid?

```
 (TP == 10) == (TP.DataLevel3Value == 10) == true;
```

I do realize the implicit conversion possibility introduces a slight lack of readability however this is a small project with only one other programmer. We are just curious if there are serious drawbacks that would inhibit functionality of the program that we are missing.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Oh sorry didn't even realize

Comment: The code is a valid boolean expression which should evaluate to `true`. The final `== true` is superfluous though.

Comment: Oh I know about the superfluous `== true` I was making sure it all evaluated to `true` that is all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely **DO NOT** write implicit casts like this. Implicit casts are reserved for when no data can be lost when converting from one type to another. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The implicit keyword is used to declare an implicit user-defined type conversion operator. Use it to enable implicit conversions between a user-defined type and another type, *if the conversion is guaranteed not to cause a loss of data*.

In your example, it *does* cause a loss of information. The property is clearly a better way to go.

You mentioned that it reduces readability, and your absolutely right. In the vast majority of cases you should favor improved readability over any syntactic sugar which merely lets you write code with fewer character, regardless of project size.

Comment: I was under the assumption that that was based on losing information for the particular cast, ala from one reference type to another reference type not from a reference type to a value type. So that applies to both? and in that case I believe you have answered the question.

Comment: Ok thanks I will post this as the answer when I can, We were just looking for clarification and that all makes sense.

Comment: @Nomad101 You're converting from a complex reference type to a `int`, so of course you're loosing information here. In practice you almost *never* need to write an implicit cast.

Comment: we were just thinking since the underlying code is basically the exact same that it would be fine for something like a return of int. as the only difference in the code for the propery and implicit conversion is the use of the `this` keyword instead of `TP`.

Comment: @Nomad101 In that case you should probably use an interface. Something like `IIntResult { int IntValue { get; } }` which you can implement in `TopLevel`. Then you could define a minimal wrapper around `int` which implements this too for returning just `int`s. You could make a implicit conversion from `int` to that wrapper class (though it probably won't be necessary).

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying thanks for the information, it has been very illuminating.